# Daterangepicker bootstrap focus event issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I don't want to open the datarangepicker dropdown menu open when focus my input 
this is jsfiddle code source

> jsfiddle.net/d2fpgz9d

Comment: May be you can disable pointer-events using css..  http://jsfiddle.net/d2fpgz9d/1/

Comment: no it is not good idea

Comment: Then you can use duplicate input box which will change data on this input box value changes..